# Understanding Function.prototype.apply

Tags: javascript, prototype

The following code is taken from the MDN page about [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply):

```
Function.prototype.construct = function (aArgs) {
    var fConstructor = this,
        fNewConstr = function () { fConstructor.apply(this, aArgs); };
    fNewConstr.prototype = fConstructor.prototype;
    return new fNewConstr();
};

function MyConstructor() {
    for (var nProp = 0; nProp < arguments.length; nProp++) {
        this["property" + nProp] = arguments[nProp];
    }
}

var myArray = [4, "Hello world!", false];
var myInstance = MyConstructor.construct(myArray);
alert(myInstance.property1); // alerts "Hello world!"
alert(myInstance instanceof MyConstructor); // alerts "true"
alert(myInstance.constructor); // alerts "MyConstructor"
```

I have two questions about this code:

1. I know that if I use `var myInstance = new MyConstructor();` it will invoke `MyConstructor()`, but how does `var myInstance = MyConstructor.construct(myArray);` invoke `MyConstructor()`?
2. `MyConstructor.construct(myArray);` was called as a method of `MyConstructor`, but that method was declared as `Function.prototype.construct`, not `MyConstructor.prototype.construct`.  What is the difference between `Function.prototype.construct` and `MyConstructor.prototype.construct`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **TL;DR:**
>
> **Q1:** It's called via the nested function, which itself is called by the `new fNewConstr()` call.  It's just to allow a list of arguments to be passed as an array without modifying how the function actually works with its arguments.
>   **Q2:** Anything on a prototype is accessible by all instances of that constructor (and `Function` is the constructor of all native functions in JavaScript), but MyConstructor is not an object instance of itself, which is why it needs to be defined in `Function.prototype`.

I've split my answer into two parts, Question 1 and Question 2:

### Question 1

Function.prototype.construct is meant to allow the passing of an array to act as an arguments list, without the use of `Function.prototype.bind`.  It calls the original function inside a nested function and the passed arguments as an array, and the prototype set to the original function's prototype.

In the code given, what `Function.prototype.construct` method does is the following

```
Function.prototype.construct = function (aArgs) {
    var fConstructor = this,
```

This first line allows us to access the function which is being called - the value of `this` (the *ThisBinding* in specification speak) in that scope is the function that we want to call.

```
        fNewConstr = function () { fConstructor.apply(this, aArgs); };
```

This next line will call the original function with `Function.prototype.apply`, which allows the arguments to that function to be passed as an array.  The reason why `this` is passed as the *ThisBinding* is to make assignments to properties of `this` go to the *ThisBinding* of the called function, which in this case will be the new object created by the "new" operator.

```
    fNewConstr.prototype = fConstructor.prototype;
```

This simply makes the prototype of the returned object created by the "new" operator the same as the calling function, as the "new" operator is called on the new constructor, not the original one.

```
    return new fNewConstr();
```

This is pretty much self-explanatory - it creates a new object with the associated values created by the constructor on the properties of `this` or returns the object returned by the function, if there is any.

What is returned is the same as if `new MyConstructor()` had been directly called, except for the way the arguments were given (just like how `Function.prototype.call()` and `Function.prototype.apply()` both exist).  For example, these two code examples are equivalent:

```
new MyConstructor(4, "Hello world!", false); // { property0: 4, property1: 'Hello world!', property2: false }
MyConstructor.construct([4, "Hello world!", false]); // { property0: 4, property1: 'Hello world!', property2: false }
```

... just like how these are equivalent:

```
function foo(a, b, c, d, e) { return a + b + c + d + e; }
foo.call(null, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5); // 15
foo.apply(null, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]); // 15
```

That's the only difference between the two - one simply calling the constructor with an arguments list, another with the arguments list represented as an array (the constructor function itself still gets the arguments as a list, not an array).

### Question 2

All instances of functions borrow from the `Function` prototype, so any methods (or for that matter, property) defined on `Function.prototype` will be available to all functions.  Take this example:

```
function foo() { return 1 + 1; }   
Function.prototype.bar = function ()
{   var result = this();
    if (typeof result === 'number' && isFinite(result)) return result + 0.5;
    return NaN;
};

foo.bar(); // 2.5
```

However, when you declare a method on `MyConstructor.prototype`, it's only available to *instances* of `MyConstructor`, not `MyConstructor` itself, as shown below:

```
function MyConstructor(num) { this.x = 1 + num; }
MyConstructor.prototype.bar = function () { return 2 + 2; };

MyConstructor.bar(); // TypeError: MyConstructor.bar is not a function
MyConstructor.x; // undefined
```

See how that doesn't work?  You need to use it on an instance of `MyConstructor`:

```
var foo = new MyConstructor(4);
foo.x; // 5
foo.bar(); // 4
```

If it's on a prototype, any edit to the prototype will affect all prototype methods/values on an object:

```
function MyConstructor(num) { this.x = 1 + num; }
MyConstructor.prototype.bar = function () { return 2 + 2; };

var foo1 = new MyConstructor(6);
foo1.bar(); // 4

MyConstructor.prototype.bar = function () { return 3 + 3; };
var foo2 = new MyConstructor(9);

foo2.bar(); // 6
foo1.bar(); // 6
```

Keep in mind though if you make a new prototype object completely, the instances created before the change will still reference the old object:

```
var foo1 = new MyConstructor(6);
foo1.bar(); // 4

MyConstructor.prototype = { bar: function () { return 3 + 3; } };

var foo2 = new MyConstructor(9);
foo2.bar(); // 6
foo1.bar(); // 4?!
```

Just remember though that properties declared directly on `MyConstructor` won't be passed on to instances:

```
MyConstructor.bar2 = function () { return 42; }; // the answer to everything?
MyConstructor.y = 3.141592653589793238462643383279502881197169399; // I only can remember that much

MyConstructor.bar2(); // 42, as you'd expect
var foo = new MyConstructor(99);

foo.bar2(); // TypeError: foo.bar2 is not defined
foo.y; // undefined
```

Prototype-based programming can be quite powerful (and in fact I much prefer it to classes, but that's a different story), but you need to understand what it does.  When used properly, you can do really great things with it - keep learning! :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to both of your questions is that `this` inside of `construct()` is set based on how you call it.

If you write `Function.prototype.construct()`, `this` will be `Function.prototype`, and it will break.

When you write `MyConstructor.construct()`, `this` is `MyConstructor`, so the code will work.

---

As a side note, this code can be greatly simplified in supporting browsers:

```
Function.prototype.construct = function (args) {
    return new (this.bind.apply(this, [null].concat(args)))();
};
```

Comment: Why are you passing null to the constructor?

Comment: @bfavaretto: that's because the first argument for `bind()` requires a parameter for the ThisBinding of the function.

Answer (score 2):

You have now created a `construct` method for every `Function`, since you accessed it with `Function.prototype`. `fConstructor` is a misleading variable, since `this` is assigned to it, which is actually referring to every `Function`. Inside a method that is a property of an Object `this` really refers to the Object to which the method belongs. `fNewConstr` would have to be `this.fNewConstr` to refer to every `Function`. In this case it's really a variable that holds a reference to a `Function` which later becomes part of the `Function` prototype with `fNewConstr.prototype = fConstructor.prototype`, which is later executed with `new fNewConstr()`. When `new fNewConstr()` is called it uses `apply()` to pass `fConstructor`, or every `Function` an Array of arguments. So your passing the Array to `MyConstrutor`.

Answer (score 1):

#### On your first question:

`MyConstructor` is called through a series of indirections, and passed an array as its arguments list. When `MyConstructor.construct(myArray)` is called, `this` inside `construct` will be `MyConstructor`. A reference to that is then stored as `fConstructor`, and a child constructor `fNewConstr` is created. That constructor invokes `MyConstructor` with `apply`, passing the elements from `myArray` as the arguments.

As a side note, that seems like an overcomplicated way to explain `Function.prototype.apply` (MDN says it's for mimicking Java, so that might explain it).

#### On your second question:

When `construct` is added to `Function.prototype`, it becomes available on all function objects (instances of `Function`), including `MyConstructor`. If you add to `MyConstructor.prototype` you affect all instances of `MyConstructor`, and when you add to `Function.prototype` you extend all function objects.